# How to search for part of a field?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a single search box which need to search for different fields such as firstname, lastname and email. Based on my current code if user enters character 'm', all users will be shown as it goes through all emails and all of them have 'm' which is included in .com.

I am wondering how I can change it to be able to search for fname,lname and email but it exclude all the characters after @ in emails. such as yahoo.com , hotmail.com, yahoo.com.us etc.

```
  criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                        .add(Restrictions.ilike("client.email", "%" + value + "%"))
                        .add(Restrictions.ilike("user.fname", "%" + query + "%"))
                        .add(Restrictions.ilike("user.lname", "%" + query + "%")));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("client.email", "%" + value + "%@%"))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("user.fname", "%" + query + "%"))
                    .add(Restrictions.ilike("user.lname", "%" + query + "%")));
```